# How to work with Twitter Api v1.1 in windows application C#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've checked that the twitter Api v1.0 is retired and v1.1 is available, I am not able to find any demo on twitter api v1.1 in windows application C#. I want to authenticate the user , get full access to read/ write the tweets and view the timeline of user using twitter api v1.1.
Please provide me any demo or steps of code user authenticate such as Tweet Deck application.

Comment: Here's an answer to a similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189521/work-with-linqtotwitter-dll-to-perform-oauth-authorization