# Work with LinqToTwitter.dll to perform oauth authorization

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, twitter, linq-to-twitter

How to perform OAUTH authorization in C# Desktop Application using LinqToTwitter dll file.
Please provide the step-by step process to achieve this task.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a Windows Forms demo on this page:

https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LINQ%20to%20Twitter%20Samples

Here's the LINQ to Twitter Security Documentation that explains OAuth and provides different ways to use OAuth with LINQ to Twitter:

https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Securing%20Your%20Applications&referringTitle=Documentation

### Update...

The Windows Forms demo is now part of the downloadable source code:

http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ReadMe.txt

Comment: Couldn't find it. Can you share it again?